# Tax sheltered investment vehicles for retirement in Canada

Tags: taxes, canada, retirement, pension, rrsp

Is there any investment vehicles to tax shelter income for retirement on top of RRSP & Pension?

I know about LIRA. When you switch job you usually get your pension funds transferred into LIRA.

Is there anything else?

Comment: Consider the TFSA & RESP.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon not sure how can you use RESP for retirement?

Comment: If you are going to try and pay for your children's post-secondary education, better to use an RESP for that purpose, thereby increasing your available funds for retirement (by increasing the impact of your saving for your children's education, effectively saving you money). If this doesn't apply to you, then it doesn't apply.